# Does Apple clang support clang-format?

Tags: macos

I am trying to change how Apple clang formats code via `clangd`. But I can't get it accept my `.clang-format`. I've tried placing it in the project root directory and `$HOME` as well.

```
IndentWidth: 4
UseTab: Always

Language: Cpp
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
```

But when format using `clangd` lsp to format the document. The tabs are being replaced with spaces. And all short functions are on a single line.

`$ clang --version`

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Running `clang-format` or `clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format` results in a command not found.

So does Apple clang not support this? Or is there a way to enable it?